# Javascript Regex: ignore subgroup when matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a string with an optional part in the middle.

Example strings are:

```
20160131_abc.pdf
20160131_abc_xx.pdf
20160131_def.pdf
```

The result should include the name of the file (w/o the optional _xx).

What I have so far:

```
/[0-9]{8}_(abc(_xx)?|def)\.pdf/i
```

This kind of works but will return the name as `abc_xx` for the second string - I only want the `abc` part of it. Is it somehow possible to ignore the subgroup?

Comment: What is the problem if you simply replace "_xx" without a regex? And then use split.

Comment: Exactly my thought. Can't `my_string = my_string.replace("_xx", "");` do the job?

Comment: I found a way, please check: [`[0-9]{8}_(abc|def(?=\.pdf))(?:_xx)?\.pdf`](https://regex101.com/r/sO5xL2/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the `def` part with a `(?=\.pdf)` lookahead that will require `.pdf` to appear right after `def` if there is `def` before the `.pdf` *and* add the optional group `(?:_xx)?` before the `.pdf`:

```
[0-9]{8}_(abc|def(?=\.pdf))(?:_xx)?\.pdf
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sO5xL2/1)

**Explanation**:

- `[0-9]{8}` - 8 digits
- `_` - underscore
- `(abc|def(?=\.pdf))` - Capture group 1 matching `abc` or `def` (`def` is only matched if `.pdf` follows it immediately)
- `(?:_xx)?` - optional `_xx` part that can only appear in the match (not in the capture) if preceded with `abc`
- `\.pdf` - literal `.pdf` substring

Comment: Note that only checking the dot in the lookahead suffices.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to omit `pdf` in the lookahead. `[0-9]{8}_(abc|def(?=\.))(?:_xx)?\.pdf` is enough, but the gain is tiny.

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-capturing groups in the regex and then "implode" the match results:

```
var re = /([0-9]{8}_)(abc|def)(?:_xx)?(\.pdf)/;
var tests = [
  '20160131_abc.pdf',
  '20160131_abc_xx.pdf',
  '20160131_def.pdf'
];
var container = document.getElementById('container');
tests.forEach(function(test){
  var match = test.match(re);
  var fileName = match.slice(1).join('');
  container.innerHTML += "test:" + test + " &rarr; ";
  container.innerHTML += fileName + "<br/>";
});
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dksf4pxq/)

Comment: this also matches `20160131_def_xx.pdf` and it shouldn't