# Regex Expressions for value extraction from URL param string

Tags: regex

I have a string where I'd like to extract some values with regex.

Whole string:

```
event=B:Rel&time=1511879856&date=20171128-143736&ref=57b3e1ab741d5a017ab8009033350b18&dir=out&src_if=GW1&dst_if=PRI1
```

I would like to isolate the values between the `=` and the next `&` creating this result set for the string given above.

```
B:Rel
1511879856
20171128-143736
57b3e1ab741d5a017ab8009033350b18
out
GW1
PRI1
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: [`&?\w*=`](https://regex101.com/r/No4Zej/2/)?

Comment: This way the matches would contain `=` and `&` You should try non-capturing groups: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619162/javascript-regex-ignore-subgroup-when-matching#36619352

Comment: `/(?:=)[a-zA-Z0-9-_%+]+(?:&)/g`
You can test on this site https://regex101.com/

Comment: @ctwheels Beware of `\w` due to utf-8 there are Umlauts out there :-)

Comment: It seems to be a query string. What language are you using? Probably there is an easier way to do what you need. Also, why do you want those values in a single string?

Comment: Then solution of Björn looks good.
This is actually the output of my telephony exchange syslog and i would loke to seperate those values for repoting purposes.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? And what if anything have you tried?

Comment: It makes more sense to create an object/dictionary of key-values, so you could use it in your reports.

Comment: I like @Stephan's better. much better. But Washington is noteworthy too? Why not just split the string using `=&`and using every second array member?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[^=]+=([^&]+)(?:&|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/Z3pcR4/1

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your language, you could `split` the input on this regex:

```
&?[^=]*=
```